# Using sed to extract number from json

Tags: sed, json

I'm struggling to use a single sed command to extract a number from some json on Linux. Given the following block:

```
{
    "key1": 100,
    "key2": 200,
}
```

I'd like the output to be 100 in the above case, but I need to capture it regardless of its length.

So far I've got this:

```
sed -n '/key1/ s/.*\: //p'
100,
```

I feel like I should be able to rid myself of the comma without piping out to 'tr' or whatever but I can't seem to manage it.

Comment: With valid JSON: `jq '.key1' file`

Comment: JSON/XML/YAML/CSV should all be parsed with a dedicated parser that understands all the corner cases of the markup language.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -e '/key1/!d' -e 's/.*\: //' -e 's/,//' testfile 
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Just search for numbers:

```
$ sed -n '/key1/ s/.*\: \([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file
100
```

or

```
$ sed -En '/key1/ s/.*\:\s+([0-9]+).*/\1/p' file
100
```

Personally, I would use `grep` instead though:

```
$ grep -oP 'key1":\s*\K\d+' file
100
```